# stop jboss by the application itself

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I am loading a module in my rest service when the jboss server start up. I wanted to shutdown the jboss server when some conditions are not met.

Please let me know the api or the command to stop the server by the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can always go with System.exit(0) I guess, but it sounds a little radical

update: mbeans maybe? https://community.jboss.org/thread/51065?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: That will stop your application but not the server.  OP wants to shut-down the server itself.